# How can I set a certain value to a member of a struct within multiple functions?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, struct, malloc

i am a beginner so please cut me some slack on this one. So I have two functions and a struct in a header file I am currently working with.

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct ArrayList
{
    // We will store an array of strings (i.e., an array of char arrays)
    char **array;

    // Size of list (i.e., number of elements that have been added to the array)
    int size;

    // Length of the array (i.e., the array's current maximum capacity)
    int capacity;

} ArrayList;
```

Here is the first function, which creates and dynamically allocates memory for an array of strings. Capacity is the length of the internal array and size is the current size (how many strings are in the array which is essentially 0.)

```
ArrayList *createArrayList(int length){

char **array = NULL;
ArrayList *n;
int size = 0;


if (length > DEFAULT_INIT_LEN)
{

array = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
n->capacity = length;
}
else
{
array = malloc(sizeof(int) * DEFAULT_INIT_LEN);
n->capacity = DEFAULT_INIT_LEN;
}

if (array == NULL)
    panic("ERROR: out of memory in Mylist!\n");

n->size = size;

printf("-> Created new ArrayList of size %d\n", n->capacity);


return *array;
```

When I try to implement a pointer to the capacity member of the ArrayList struct inside another function within the same file, it is uninitialized instead of set as the value from the previous function. I.e. in createArrayList, n->capacity is equal to 10, but when used in printArrayList it is uninitialized and a random number appears such as 122843753.:

```
void printArrayList(ArrayList *list)
{


printf("\n%d", list->capacity);


return NULL;
}
```

My question is, how can I make it so all these functions "share" the same value when referring to the struct members. I.E. the first function prints -> Created new ArrayList of size 10, and the second function prints 10 as well.  Also, I have to do this without changing the struct function itself. Sorry if this is a poorly worded question, but I can further clarify if it is confusing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be more consistent in your naming. For example, you have a function parameter named `length` that corresponds to a structure field named `capacity`, and your output-text refers to it as `size` -- even though you actually have a different field that *is* named `size`. This sort of inconsistency more or less guarantees that you will have bugs, since consistent naming is the only way to keep track of things and remember what they mean.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of major issues with this code, in `createArrayList` you are returning `array` which is a `char **` but you should be returning an `ArrayList *` which is what `n` is. So it looks like you want to assign `array` to `n->array`. The next issue is that `n` is an `ArrayList *` but you do not allocate memory for `n`.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @KarimElsheikh Maybe I misread the question but as far as I can tell you are essentially trying to share the data correctly by using pointers but your implementation has errors. Once you fix these errors you should be ok.

Comment: Its my fault for wording the question incorrectly. My question essentially has nothing to do with the code, I just included it as a background. I essentially want x->capacity in the first function to equal y->capacity in the second function automatically, how is this possible?

Comment: The answer is correct, unless you're messing with function calls in ways you haven't mentioned yet. Stop ignoring it and read again.

Comment: @KarimElsheikh It will **if** you fix the problems!